# How to add functions in entity manager configuration doctrine in zend framework 3

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3, doctrine-query

I have currently a controller and a controller factory

AbcControllerFactory

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
    $entityManager                   =  $container->get("doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default");
    return new AbcController($entityManager);
}
```

And AbcController

```
private $entityManager;
public function __construct($entityManager){
    $this->entityManager             =  $entityManager;
}
```

I am trying to use this doctrine library

[doctrine library for json functions](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions)

but the only issue is I'm stuck in adding these functions

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->addCustomStringFunction(DqlFunctions\JsonExtract::FUNCTION_NAME, DqlFunctions\JsonExtract::class);
$config->addCustomStringFunction(DqlFunctions\JsonSearch::FUNCTION_NAME, DqlFunctions\JsonSearch::class);
```

I'm fairly new to this doctrine bit. Can anyone help how should I add these function in the existing entity manager configuration

This is my local.php file where all information is stored

```
return [
"doctrine" => [
    "connection" => [
        "orm_default" => [
            "driverClass" => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
            "params" => [
                "driver"             => "pdo_mysql",
                "dsn"                => "mysql:dbname=abc;host=localhost;charset=utf8",
                "host"     => "localhost",
                "user"     => "root",
                "password" => "",
                "dbname"   => "abc",
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is a bit sluggish from me. However, I found out you could add function like this in controller:

```
$this->entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction(DqlFunctions\JsonExtract::FUNCTION_NAME, DqlFunctions\JsonExtract::class);
$this->entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction(DqlFunctions\JsonSearch::FUNCTION_NAME, DqlFunctions\JsonSearch::class);
```